# Could Java be made to run without a GC

Tags: java, rust

I can't find much online on this but here is my thought, a language like rust analyses on compile when to free objects from memory. Why can't the same be done with Java then we don't need a garbage collector. Unless it's because this would make the coding even more complicated.

So the question being could the Java compiler manage memory before runtime

Comment: If I remember correctly JavaCard either works GC-less or at least has GC-less configurations. So while it *is* possible in specific configurations the resulting system is also not a very useful one for general-purpose work (in other words: it only works for code that's specifically written for that mode).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java can do "simple" cleanups, where it knows for sure that an object didn't leak from the stack and thus is safe to clean up when the stack is cleaned up. Such [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) is also used in other ways, for example to determine whether the lock needs to be taken when you enter a `synchronized` block: if the reference is guaranteed to be stack-confined, you don't need to take the lock because there is no risk of any other thread seeing it.

The difference between Java and Rust is that Rust has a strict notion of ownership, so it is *possible* to know statically when *all* objects can be cleaned up safely; Java doesn't have this notion, so it has to, in general, rely on the GC to work it out.

So, essentially, no, Java can't do without a GC, because that is how the language was designed; Rust can do without a GC because that is how that language was designed.

Comment: Also, you need to manually handle reference cycles if you are using Arc/ Rc to prevent leaking. In GCed languages like Java it is not ever problem.

Comment: @Angelicos thanks, you're showing up my lack of knowledge of Rust :) I presume you're referring to [reference counting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html)? Sure: the thing is that Rust provides a mechanism to manually handle memory management in this case, whereas Java doesn't.

Comment: The problem with Arcs, that you can make memory leak with them. Example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15d77b91507e8f2aa2097f6f1f965f20  Java GC, in contrast, uses reachability analysys which can prove that entire reference cycle is unreachable.